# Where does the hierarchical reinforcement learning framework name "MAXQ" come from?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, terminology, hierarchical-rl, maxq

I've been researching different frameworks for hierarchical RL (mainly options, HAMs, and MAXQ) and noticed that both options and HAMs have names that relate to how they function. I can't seem to find anything stating how MAXQ got its name and I was wondering if anyone knew what the name was referencing.

Comment: Hello. Have you already looked at the MAXQ paper? The answer probably lies there. If you find the answer to your own question, feel free to write a formal answer below, so that future readers can also see it.